# light dependent 5V switch

Tags: transistors, switches, photoresistor

I wired up this light dependent switch

[image: https://craftronixlab.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/1341308022.jpg]

which works fine.  when in daylight and covered.  how can i make it work when the light source is dimmer?  ie is it a case of changing 1 of the resistors?

Comment: I think you can reduce the resistor on BJT's base or the 10k ohm resistor. What's the model of your LDR?

Comment: just a standard http://www.amazon.co.uk/10Pcs-GL5528-Dependent-Resistor-Photoresistor/dp/B009AO35Q8

Answer (score 1):

You can make it a bit more sensitive by increasing the 10K resistor, but there is not enough current gain in one BJT to make it work in very dim light.

If you replace the BC547 with an n-channel MOSFET you can increase the 10K to 100K or 1M and make it very sensitive.

Alternately, connect a second BC547 to the first in a [Darlington](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darlington_transistor) configuration (and increase the 10K).

[image: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/78/Darlington_pair_diagram.svg/133px-Darlington_pair_diagram.svg.png]

Answer (score 0):

**connect two LDR in parallel** it will increase the sensitivity and it will operate in dim light sources. you can also eliminate the 1.2K base resistance.